# Melhor Tipo Mysql para contabilizar os acessos

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma base de dados onde contém arquivos PDF, só que estou querendo contabilizar quantas visualizações teve esse arquivo. A estrutura de contabilizar está pronta, pois foi feita em PHP/Mysql, só que estou com uma dúvida. Normalmente coloco o Tipo Varchar(255), mas para esse tipo é ideal para fazer essa contagem? A cada acesso, irei usar o UPDATE.

Comment: A pessoa que negativou, poderia ao menos dizer o motivo? Afinal é uma dúvida que se refere a programação.

Comment: Se entendi bem você quer armazenar o total de visualizações, ou seja, um número. Por que a coluna não seria `bigint`?

Comment: Olá rLinhares. Certo. Ela aceitaria a soma de cada acesso? Ou seja. A cada acesso, eu teria que somar com + 1, pois nunca usei esse Tipo.

Comment: Se vc quer calcular (soma / subtração e etc) um valor, o mesmo deve estar numa coluna numérica e não numa `VARCHAR`, como mencionado pelo @rLinhares o certo é `bigint`, `Integer` ou alguma na mesma linha.

Comment: Certo. Vou seguir a dica de vocês. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Sim, é um campo numérico, não teria problema

Comment: Pergunta um "bocado" forçada, talvez seria melhor acrescentar/perguntar as desvantagens na utilização de um`varchar` em vez de um `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contagem é numérico, e são valores inteiros e positivos.

O tipo adequado para isso, portanto, é `INTEGER UNSIGNED` (inteiro SEM sinal). Nesta família, temos estas possibilidades:

```
TIPO        BYTES   SIGNED                        UNSIGNED
=========== ======= ============================= =====================
TINYINT     1       de -128 a 127                 de 0 a 255
SMALLINT    2       de -32768 a 32767             de 0 a 65535
MEDIUMINT   3       de -8388608 a 8388607         de 0 a 16777215
INT         4       de -2147483648 a 2147483647   de 0 a 4294967295
BIGINT      8       de -2^63 a 2^63-1             de 0 a 2^64-1
```

Escolha o tipo que melhor atender o seu caso, prevendo o número máximo que pretende armazenar.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html